# Angular http put - incorrect method is called

Tags: angular, http

I have some `http.put` wrapper. And it results in calling incorrect PUT overload. I need the one that returns `Observable<Object>`, but instead `Observable<ArrayBuffer>` is called. Here is my wrapper for `http.put` in Angular app:

```
  public put(endpoint: string, data?: any, options?) {
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    if (options == undefined) {
      options = {};
    }
    options.headers = this.headers;

    return this.http.put(this.uri + endpoint, jsonData, options);
  }
```

If I call it like this, then even during compilation it decides to cal the following http.put overload:

```
put(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

However, I need to call the one that return sjust object:

```
 put(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<Object>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `responseType: 'json'` in `options`.

```
  public put(endpoint: string, data?: any, options?) {
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    if (options == undefined) {
      options = {};
    }
    options.headers = this.headers;
    options.responseType = 'json';

    return this.http.put(this.uri + endpoint, jsonData, options);
  }
```

Comment: Is still leads to incorrect PUT method. It even shows error during ng build. "hereICallPutMethod".then((answer: string) this row gives error during build. Ant it says Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.